# Kibana: store and load Kibana index from another Elasticsearch server?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Hihi everyone

In the configuration file of Kibana,  "config.js" we can only configure elasticsearch address and the name of the kibana index, i would like to be able to configure another ES adress for the the kibana index.

So i could store and load kibana dashboard from/to another ES server that the one i'm requesting  data.

Could anyone please help ;) thanks

Hyacinthe

Comment: What do you  mean by another ES. If another ES is a part of the cluster, all the indexes of that ES also can be pointed in kibana.

Comment: It's a configuration problem. You only have to fill the elasticsearch address in the config file. By default, the index where kibana's dashboard will be saved is your_es_adress/kibana-int. I would like the be able to set another address like es_somewhere_else/kibana-int

Comment: Kibana used elastic address specified in its configuration file for featching a data. It is able to featch data from all the cluster for that ES.So your kibana dashboard i.e kibana-int should be saved in the specified ES cluster environment only. I don't understand why you need to save kibana dashboard in a seprate ES instance which is not a part of ES cluster.

Comment: @NirdeshSharma : it's because i have some restriction in my infrastructure, but i will do it in another way. Thanks guys

Comment: @NirdeshSharma Don't want to sound harsh, but the fact you don't understand why he wants that does not prevent you from giving an answer. I have the same restrictions and would have loved to know a solution to that problem.